Python Classes: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
Why does accessing the class attribute foo fail when building a tuple with non-zero length only?
class Foo:
    foo = 42
    
    bar_ok1 = (foo for _ in range(10))
    bar_ok2 = tuple(foo for _ in [])
    
    bar_fail1 = tuple(foo for _ in range(10))
    bar_fail2 = tuple(foo for _ in [0, 1, 2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "main.py", line 7, in Foo
    bar_fail1 = tuple(foo for _ in range(10))
  File "main.py", line 7, in <genexpr>
    bar_fail1 = tuple(foo for _ in range(10))
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined


The ok cases don't access foo because one is a generator and the other performs zero iterations. If you need an existing duplicate to explain that a generator is lazily evaluated, I'm sure I can find one; but I don't understand why you'd be writing one if you didn't know this. The fact that a loop that performs zero iterations won't cause a NameError seems trivial since this is a runtime error. So the actual underlying question here is why the failing cases fail. That's because they look for foo in the global namespace, not the class - see the linked duplicate.

A debugging hint: you can pass compiling but non-working code to dis.dis as a multi-line string literal. The disassembly for each generator expression will show that foo is accessed via LOAD_GLOBAL. It's the same as how methods inside the class would still have to specify Foo.foo to access the shared value.

(Sorry, I guess the inability of methods to access the class scope directly is a bit different. But it still boils down to the bytecode looking for that name in the global scope.)

That's because bar_ok1 is not evaluated yet, as it defines a generator, and the foo value is not accessed on class definition. The foo value is also not accessed for bar_ok2, as does it not perform the iteration at all (empty list).
In contrast, the bar_fail* attributes are evaluated on class definition.
Run the following and you will notice it fails for bar_ok1:
class Foo:
    foo = 42
    
    bar_ok1 = (foo for _ in range(10))
    bar_ok2 = tuple(foo for _ in [])
    
    #bar_fail1 = tuple(foo for _ in range(10))
    #bar_fail2 = tuple(foo for _ in [0, 1, 2])

list(Foo.bar_ok1)
list(Foo.bar_ok2)

list(Foo.bar_ok2) will produce an empty list, as there are no elements to loop over and no reason to check the foo value.

Generator expressions/comprehensions and class definitions have different scopes. The reason why bar_ok1 = (foo for _ in range(10)) does not raise a NameError and bar_fail1 = tuple(foo for _ in range(10)) does is because everything within the body of class Foo is executed first.
Since (foo for _ in range(10)) is a generator expression, it is not executed until the class Foo is executed (different scope). Wrapping this generator in a tuple() expression, however, causes the generator to execute leading to the NameError. The line bar_ok2 = tuple(foo for _ in []) does not execute in the first place since the range is empty.
